# Some kinda JSTL Messages Tag

Tags: java, jstl, message, presentation, custom-tag

Is there a JSTL tag specifically for displaying messages, and only if there are messages to display? So that I don't have to surround the displaying with an "c:if" tag.

If so, how do I use it? How should I add the messages to be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for `c:out`.  For example, this should display the value of `person.name`, or nothing if it is `null`.

```
    <c:out value="${person.name}" />
```

If you want to display a default value in the case of a `null`, then:

```
    <c:out value="${person.name}" default="no name" />
```

or

```
    <c:out value="${person.name}">no name</c:out>
```

(If this doesn't answer your question, you need to be more explicit about what you mean by "messages" ... and how you want them to be displayed.)

---

If you have zero or more messages in a collection:

```
    <c:forEach items="${messages}" var="message">
        <c:out value="${message}"/>
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I have multiple messages? I mean, if I have a Collection of messages, and I want to display them as a list.

Comment: @HenriqueOrdine, you could use a simple EL expression checking if the collection is empty, like: `${not empty yourCollection} ? 'not empty' : 'empty'`

Comment: @Zaki, this way if my collection is not empty, instead of displaying a list of messages on the page, I'd just display the String "not empty".

Comment: @HenriqueOrdine, it's a ternary expression in EL; you could test if the collection is empty or not empty,for example: `${empty yourCollection} ? 'do your thing here if its empty' : 'do your thing here if not empty'`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by 'do your thing here if not empty'. That just looks like a string to me.